# Некорректное отображение сайта в WebView при вертикальной ориентации телефона

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

Сегодня я проверял `WebView`, и решил открыть с его помощью один сайт. Сайт открылся, но в вертикальном положении отображался некорректно, и это при том, что в браузере всё работает хорошо. В чём может быть проблема и как её решить?

Прилагаю код и скриншоты:

[Вертикальная ориентация](https://pp.userapi.com/c846020/v846020275/2e591/HaIW_jqPmOQ.jpg)

[Горизонтальная ориентация](https://pp.userapi.com/c846020/v846020275/2e599/Do7LUzeDdoQ.jpg)

Код MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webview=findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("https://www.znak.com/2017-04-12/muzey_istorii_ekaterinburga_ichet_oko_saurona_dlya_vodonapornoy_bashni_na_plotinke");


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Код activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Откройте её в родном браузере Андроида и станет понятно кто виноват.

Comment: В родном браузере всё работает нормально.